# Change the color of a cell in gridview devexpress not row

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress

I have a `grid view devexpress c#` That shows lots of data,i need to set the color of cell based on data value  as you can see :

```
  private void gridView_RowStyle_1(object sender, RowStyleEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.RowHandle >= 0)
            {


                // Some condition
                if (gridView.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, gridView.Columns["Id"]).ToString() == "2")
                {
                    e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Green;
                }
            }
        }
```

But this function change the whole row color not the cell .How can i set the color of the cell ?

Comment: here grid is simple or devexpress grid ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use GridView.RowCellStyle event as follows:

```
    void gridView1_RowCellStyle( object sender, RowCellStyleEventArgs e)
    {
       GridView currentView = sender as GridView;
       if (e.Column.FieldName == "Customer" )
       {
          bool value = Convert.ToBoolean(currentView.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, "Flag_Customer" ));
           if (value)
           e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Red;
       }
       if (e.Column.FieldName == "Vendor" )
       {
          bool value = Convert.ToBoolean(currentView.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, "Flat_Vendor" ));
          if (value)
          e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Red;
       }
    }
```